# Is it possible to know past indices of removed elements from ListChangeListener.Change<E>?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I am trying to write a wrapper for [`ObservaleList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html). This requires to resend all change events from underlying list. Unfortunately, I see no any way to know indices of removed elements from [`Change`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html). It is only possible to get the list of removed elements with `getRemoved()` and know their number with `getRemovedSize()`. But there is nothing to pass to [`ObservaleListBase#nextRemove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableListBase.html#nextRemove-int-E-)

Is it possible to fulfil?

Comment: maybe getFrom/getTo?

Comment: What do you mean by "resend all changes"? Do you implement `ObservableList` and use an internal instance? Can't you add a listener to that list and re-fire the change with the `Change` object itself?

Comment: See also [*How to concatenate observable lists in JavaFX?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37524662/230513)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change.getFrom()` to get the from index and `change.getTo()` to get the to index. For example:

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.getItems().addAll("test", "test2", "test3", "test2");

listView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) c -> {
    while(c.next()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("From: %d, To: %d", c.getFrom(), c.getTo()));
    }
});

listView.getItems().removeAll("test2");
```

Outputs:

```
From: 1, To: 1
From: 2, To: 2
```